# How to install particular version (not latest) of software via YUM?

Tags: linux, php, yum

I recently installed CentOS 6.3 on a VPS. The version on PHP that comes with CentOS is 5.3.3, which is not the final, stable PHP 5.3 version. The final version was 5.3.26.

Using the default `yum` repo's, you can't get anything beyond 5.3.3. But I need to update the final, most stable version. After some research, a lot of people recommend using the Remi Repository for this. So I install the repo and `yum info php`:

```
Installed Packages
php.x86_64        5.3.3-22.el6        @base

Available Packages
php.x86_64        5.4.16-1.el6.remi        remi
```

And then

`yum info php --showduplicates`

```
Installed Packages
php.x86_64        5.3.3-22.el6        @base

Available Packages
php.x86_64        5.4.15-1.el6.remi        remi
php.x86_64        5.4.16-1.el6.remi        remi
```

Okay, so the latest and greatest PHP is 5.4.16, which the remi repository has. But I can't use this one for various compatibility reasons. I need 5.3.26. Is it not in the repository? Does the repo not contain every version? Or does it just contain the latest? If there are other versions available in the repository, how do I find them or browse them? How do I install what I need using YUM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the repository does not contain all versions.  Most repo owners clean out older rpms periodically.  It's common to see them keep the last 2 or last 3 versions of things.

In the case of the remi repo, they keep the "old" stuff [here](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/olds/x86_64/).  Note that this is NOT a repo that you can point yum at, it's just a directory containing the old rpms.  You can probably download the older rpm from that and install it with yum localinstall.  It may have some other requirements that you'll have to pull from the archive.